# Typescript 1.4 Union types, false type mis-match error

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I have been playing around with union types in Typescript 1.4 and I have encountered a false type mismatch error.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something?

error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
/** @inheritdoc */
public log(logLevel : LogLevel, message : string|Object, exception?: Exception): void {
    // Check if the message is of type Object
    if (Util.isObject(message)) {
        // Log the message object
        this.logObject(logLevel, message, exception);
    }
    // Check if the message is of type string
    else if(Util.isString(message)) {
        // Log the message
        this.logMessage(logLevel, message, exception);
    }
}

class Util {

    protected static TYPE_STRING = 'string';

    public static isString(object : any): boolean {
        return (typeof object === Util.TYPE_STRING);
    }

    public static isObject(object : any): boolean {
        return (object instanceof Object);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typescript compiler does not know your intent with the `isString` and `isObject` methods, and can't flow the types correctly. You should inline the type-tests:

```
/** @inheritdoc */
public log(logLevel : LogLevel, message : string|Object, exception?: Exception): void {
    // Check if the message is of type Object
    if (message instanceof Object) {
        // Log the message object
        this.logObject(logLevel, message, exception);
    }
    // Check if the message is of type string
    else if (typeof message === 'string') {
        // Log the message
        this.logMessage(logLevel, message, exception);
    }
}
```

If you do not want to do that, you could instead assert the type:

```
/** @inheritdoc */
public log(logLevel : LogLevel, message : string|Object, exception?: Exception): void {
    // Check if the message is of type Object
    if (Util.isObject(message)) {
        // Log the message object
        this.logObject(logLevel, <Object> message, exception);
    }
    // Check if the message is of type string
    else if(Util.isString(message)) {
        // Log the message
        this.logMessage(logLevel, <string> message, exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for type assertion/casting. Thanks.

Comment: It is not casting. There is no run-time check involved with the assertion.

Comment: Your `Util.isString` is set to accept an argument of type `any`. Unless you have changed that, my code would work.